# NSMutableArray synchronization with priority

Tags: objective-c

I have some NSMutableArray , that i am adding object to in another thread (async) , with :

```
 @synchronized(array)
                        {
                            [array addObject:backImageView];
                        }
```

Than, there is another place where i remove objects from him, in the main thread,

```
//remove from array
    for(UIImageView *image in array)
        if( (image.tag< page-numPagesLoads || image.tag> page+numPagesLoads) && image.tag!=-11)
            [array removeObject:image];
```

Question is, that i want to give a better priority to the place who adds the object to him, so no matter what, stop the use of this array , add new object, and if in the next time you try to remove object you dont interrupted by the "add object" , and remove .

How would you do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The adding and removing objects from an array will happen quickly enough that there will be no discernible advantage to adding some complicated prioritization logic here. Usually you'd just adopt the simple and logical "first come, first serve" approach inherent in all locks/queues/etc.

FYI, I don't see you using `@synchronized` in your second example, but I assume you were using it there, too, but that it was omitted for the sake of brevity. When using locks to synchronize objects across multiple threads, you have to use those locks everywhere you use this object.

Personally, because (a) you're dealing with such a trivial and fast operation; and (b) you're dealing with an array of UI objects, I'd be inclined to suggest you cut the Gordian knot, and just dispatching all the manipulation of this array (and the corresponding UIKit objects) to the main queue, which simplifies your task.